# What is the song Muse performs on the rooftop of A-rise's school?

Tags: music, love-live

What is the song Muse performs on the rooftop of A-rise's school?

It was to qualify for the idol tournament, I think, and they wore blue dresses.

Answer (score 2):

The song they perform in season 2 episode 3 on top of A-RISE's school is ["Yume no Tobira"](http://love-live.wikia.com/wiki/Yume_no_Tobira).